# Error while trying to deploy app on google app engine

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, app.yaml

I'm working on deploying a python 3.6 script on google app engine with a flexible runtime. I couldn't deploy it and this is the error I got:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out waiting for the app infrastructure to become healthy.
```

So I checked what was wrong with a `gcloud app deploy --verbosity debug` and I got that explanation:

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/[Project ID]/operations/2d76a22c-64d7-4e2e-95ee-7c01ee09d42a] not complete. Waiting to retry.
```

I'm been googling and trying to find a solution and the closest I could get was that this was a problem with my app.yaml file. Now, I'm working with .yaml files for the first time so I copied the one on the google documentation and just changed the entry point to my script.

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: python main.py

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.6

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and help to get this script setup on app engine is really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just be patient.  Sometimes it takes longer than at other times.  If there is an error, it will tell you so.  If there are many updated files, it will take a while to upload and save them.  Sometimes, you have to try again, as it may fail for reasons on the backend

Comment: Haha, I guess patience is a virtue for a reason :D